# How to choose the right hydration pack for me

Tags: shopping, bags, hydration

Want some advice for hydration pack. Do I need a hydration pack for my 3 or 4 hours biking? and How to choose the right hydration pack for me? any accommodation? what do you use?

Comment: Theres a ton of things missing. Is it road riding? Mountain biking? Whats the temperature? Whats the availability of water? etc.

Comment: as said batman there are a some stuff missing in your question. So I gonna tell you what I have. I have two deuter backpacks (one big one small) they boot are capable of carry hydration packs so I got a cheap one just to give it a try and well it works but only used it once I found no need to have that much water also it is more comfortable to have one or two water bottles (I have 2 of 7500 ml so it is a lot of water) and not wear any backpack. Maybe on some really long ride or hiking it worth it as you must also carry more stuff that just water.

Comment: Depending on your temperatures, 4 hours might be 8 bottles, or it might be one.  Please give us more info by using the **EDIT** link straight below your question.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of Thumb: a water bottle an hour

That rule of thumb slides from person to person... me I am more like a 1/2 bottle per hour a little more if it is hot and a little less if I am mountain biking with my dog just joying being outside.

On a 3-4 hour road ride with no water stops available along the way I would take two bottles... if it was exceptionally hot I may add a small bottle to my jersey pocket.  On a similar time duration mountain bike ride (sans dog) I would use a hydration pack.

So, things to consider:

1. Do you just want the pack for hydration or do you want to carry stuff in the pack as well (e.g. Tools, pump, jacket, food, etc..)
2. After gauging your consumption rate (only you can do this) and considering  a bottle is 22-26 oz determine the bladder size you need/feel confident will provide the amount of hydration required for your targeted activities.

Once you answer those questions I am pretty sure you will be able to look at your selections and make all the little personal preferences relative to style and selection necessary to wind up with a hydration pack that works for your needs.